# Dimension of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

The following problem was subject of examination that was taken place in June. The document is [here](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~nbos/commalg/tentamen_2013.pdf). Problem 1 states:

> The tensor product $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb{Q}$ is a vector space
>   over $\mathbb{Q}$ by multiplication in the left factor, i.e.
>   $\lambda(x\otimes y)=(\lambda x)\otimes y$ for $\lambda, x,
>  y\in\mathbb{Q}$. What is the dimension of
>   $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$ as a vector space over
>   $\mathbb{Q}$?

I only know the definition of tensor product for modules (via universal property). How does one go about calculating dimension of such a vector space?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ isn't a field so it doesn't make sense to ask about vector spaces over the integers. Perhaps what was meant was module?

Comment: @kahen: sorry it was a typo

Comment: As a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$? Don't you mean as a free module?

Comment: @Dedalus: I meant $\mathbb{Q}$. Fixed.

Comment: I advocate [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329720/isomorphic-group-with-g-mathbb-z-2-infty-oplus-frac-mathbb-q-mathbb-z/329860#329860) as a good discussion of three important properties of tensor products, in particular #3 is relevant to this question. (BenjaLim generalizes it a bit.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Begin by checking

\begin{align}\frac{a}{b}\otimes \frac{c}{d}&=\frac{ad}{bd}\otimes\frac{c}{d}\\
&=\frac{a}{bd}\otimes\frac{cd}{d}\\
&=\frac{a}{bd}\otimes c\\
&=\frac{ac}{bd}\otimes 1
\end{align}

So, $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}$.

Now you can end it.

Comment: Obviously, the more general things going on here is that $\Frac(R)\otimes_R\Frac(R)$ is isomorphic to $\Frac(R)$ as a $\Frac(R)$-module.

Comment: There is a subtle point in this year which perhaps should be pointed out to the OP. The last step is not in general legit for general modules (which don't have $1$ in them, e.g. $\Bbb{2}\Bbb{Z}$ as a $\Bbb{Z} - module).

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Ah indeed! A very nice presentation is given in Keith Conrad's [expository note](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) on tensor products. (Theorem 4.20, and Example 4.21)

Answer (score 11):

I just want to make remark that RGB's answer more generally shows the following. Suppose $M,N$ are $S^{-1}A$ - modules. Then we can form both $M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} N$ and $M \otimes N$. The former is an $S^{-1}A$ - module and the latter an $A$ - module by restriction of scalars. The **ultimate point** now is this:
$M \otimes_A N$ ***already has*** the structure of an $S^{-1}A$ - module built into it! Thus $M \otimes_{S^{-1}A} N$ and $M \otimes_A N$ are ***canonically isomorphic*** as $S^{-1}A$ modules; this is basically the content of RGB's answer.

If you want to show $\Bbb{Q} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q} \cong \Bbb{Q}$ using universal properties here is what we do: Let $f : \Bbb{Q} \times \Bbb{Q} \to M$ be a $\Bbb{Z}$ - bilinear map. Consider $\pi : \Bbb{Q} \times \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{Q}$ that sends $(a,b)$ to $ab$. Now we have linearity in the first variable because  $$\begin{eqnarray*} \pi(na_1 + ma_2,b) &=& (na_1+ma_2)b \\
 &=& n(a_1b) + m(a_2b) \\
&=& n\pi(a_1,b) + m\pi(a_2,b)\end{eqnarray*}$$
for any $a_1,a_2,b \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $n,m\in \Bbb{Z}$. By symmetry linearity in the second variable follows and so $\pi$ is bilinear. Let us now define a map $g : \Bbb{Q} \to M$  by $g(a) = f(a,1)$ for any $a \in \Bbb{Q}$. This map $g$ is linear because $f$ is linear in the first variable. Also $g$ is well - defined and furthermore is unique: ***Any linear map*** out of $\Bbb{Q}$ to $M$ $\tilde{g}$ such that $\tilde{g} \circ \pi = f$ ***must necessarily satisfy*** $$ \tilde{g}(a) = \tilde{g}(\pi(a,1)) = f(a,1).$$

Thus we have shown that $\Bbb{Q}$ satisfies the universal property of $\Bbb{Q} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q}$ and so the answer to your question comes easily: $\dim_\Bbb{Q} \Bbb{Q} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to compose this detailed answer. I am drawing diagrams to convince myself :)

Comment: +1. why are they canonically isomorphic? is there a "functorial" proof? I know that $-\otimes_{A} S^{-1}A\cong S^{-1}$ (functorial isom.)

Comment: I have some concerns about the proof. 1) If you want to show the universal property is satisfied for the $\mathbb{Z}$ module $\mathbb{Q}$ then you would have to show that $g\circ \pi=f$ and I am not sure how to show this by using the $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure on $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution using category theory : tensor product is the fiber coproduct in the category of commutative rings. $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism since it's a localization.

If $A \rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism, and $B \rightarrow C, B \rightarrow D$ are any morphisms, then $C \coprod_A D \simeq C \coprod_B D$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{Q}$