# tesnsor product of two copies of $\Bbb{R}$ over $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I would like to know what would be tensor product of set of reals over reals would be?

That is, $\Bbb{R} \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{R}$

I think it should be $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ as tensor product combines two vector spaces to give another vector space. Therefore, it should be $\Bbb{R}^2$ but sometimes it doesn't.

Similarly, what would be $\Bbb{R} \otimes_\Bbb{Z} \Bbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good enough reason; indeed, one always has $V \otimes_k k \simeq V$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, $V\otimes_kk\cong V$ for any vector space $V$ over a field $k$. Tensoring against another space does not always increase dimension. Indeed one purpose of tensoring is to *extend scalars* (this application, among others, is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332011/motivation-for-the-tensor-product/332029#332029)), and rather trivially if we extend scalars to the field extension $k/k$ ... we have introduced no new scalars at all, and so have done nothing really. Can you think of the isomorphism $V\otimes_kk\cong V$?

That takes care of $\Bbb R\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb R$. What about $\Bbb R\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R$? I assume you mean as a vector space over $\Bbb R$, as opposed to as a ring. Take any vector space basis of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ (invoking such a thing requires some Choice) writing $\Bbb R=\bigoplus_B\Bbb Qc$ as $c$ ranges over the basis. Then I leave you to check that the set $\{1\otimes c:c\in B\}$ is an $\Bbb R$-basis for $\Bbb R \otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R$. It is important to *really* understand what elements of tensor products look like in order for this to be an intuitive fact. Some technology can also be used: writing $\Bbb R$ as an uncountable direct sum of copies of $\Bbb Q$ (using Choice to invoke a basis for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$), using the fact that tensor products distribute over direct sums, and that tensoring over a domain (like $\Bbb Z$) against its fraction field (like $\Bbb Q$) does not change anything. (See the "sliding" and "distributivity" rules over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329720/isomorphic-group-with-g-mathbb-z-2-infty-oplus-frac-mathbb-q-mathbb-z/329860#329860).)

Comment: One should point out that the easiest way to see $\mathbb R \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb R \simeq \mathbb R$ is to first note that for any simple tensor we have $a \otimes b = 1 \otimes ab$ and then for any sum of those $1 \otimes a + 1 \otimes b = 1 \otimes (a + b)$.  Thus every element of $\mathbb R \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb R$ is a simple tensor of the form $1 \otimes a$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$\phi: \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} $$ which acts on elementary tensors in the following way $$(a,b) \mapsto ab $$ This map is $\Bbb{R}$-bilinear and so by the universal property of tensor product there is a $\Bbb{R}$-linear map $$\phi' : \Bbb{R} \otimes_{\Bbb{R}} \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} $$ $$ a \otimes_{\Bbb{R}} b \mapsto ab $$ The inverse of $\phi'$ is the $\Bbb{R}$-linear map $$\lambda : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} \otimes_{\Bbb{R}} \Bbb{R}$$ $$r \mapsto 1 \otimes_{\Bbb{R}} r$$ as you can check.

Thus $$\Bbb{R} \otimes_{\Bbb{R}} \Bbb{R} \cong \Bbb{R}$$ as $\Bbb{R}$-modules.